# error on line 1 of config file 'v3.ext' when generating a self-signed ceertificate

Tags: ssl, https

I'm attempting to create a self signed SSL cert and when I go to generate the SSL cert I got the following error:

> error on line 1 of config file 'v3.ext'

The command I'm using to generate the cert is:

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -extfile v3.ext -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

And my v3.ext file is as follows:

```
$ cat v3.ext
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
 
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = <common_name>
$
```

So I guess my question is what's wrong with my v3.ext. The guide I'm following is here: 
https://ksearch.wordpress.com/2017/08/22/generate-and-import-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-mac-osx-sierra/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading BOM from the ext file.  You can use Notepad++ to change the encoding to UTF-8 and save it without a BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your conf file looks odd to me. The format I’ve always used for self signed or pki signed certs is along these lines:

```
[ req ]
default_bits       = 4096
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default         = GB
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = England
localityName                = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = Brighton
organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Hallmarkdesign
commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max              = 64
commonName_default          = localhost

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = your-website.dev
DNS.2   = another-website.dev
```